# where to close the cursor?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, cursor

i have a cursor that I am using in the following code.  But I want to close the cursor after it is used and no longer needed.  The problem is that the cursor is used in the return statement, but I can't close it after the return statement because that is unreachable code.  It is used in the return statement so I can't close it above that line.  How do I close the cursor?    This is not like the old managedQuery, I assume that you have to close it.

```
   public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
      // cursor.close() <--- not possible because it is unreachable code after return
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add in my original post.  This is in a Service, not an Activity so I guess that I can't use startManagingCursor() in a Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign it to a String object then close cursor and return it.

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
cursor.close();
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Would using a finally block work for you? I'm not experienced in your particular problem but could you put your cleanup in the finally block that would otherwise be bypassed by the return statement:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Just an idea! Don't shoot me if not!

Answer (score 1):

Try - Finally to the rescue...

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {

  Cursor cursor = null;

  try {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();


    return   cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    finally {
     if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close(); // close the cursor
    }


 }
```

**NOTE**

Just noted another answer below..
If you're inside an activity, you can call `startManaginCursor()` and pass the `cursor` instance so Android will manage its lifetime. If you don't have access to Android Application Context (ex: code is in a utility class) use above method. (and sprinkle a bit of some error handling ;) )

Comment: that is a fantastic idea, however for this problem I like the simpler way of assigning to a temporary string object.

Answer (score 0):

if (this.daoDatabase != null) {

```
        final Cursor genericCursor = this.daoDatabase.query(this.tableName, null, null, null, null, null, orderByCriteria);

        if (genericCursor != null) {
            if (genericCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                   // do stuff...
                } while (genericCursor.moveToNext());
            }
            genericCursor.close();
        }
    }
```